# share videoURL on instagram app iOS

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, sharing

```
func shareVideoToInstagram() {
    let strURL = "http://mobmp4.org/files/data/2480/Tutak%20Tutak%20Tutiya%20Title%20Song%20-%20Remix%20-%20Drunx%20-%20Mp4.mp4"

    let caption = "Some Preloaded Caption"
    let captionStr = caption.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)! as String

    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: strURL, isDirectory: false)
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

    library.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: videoURL) { (newURL, error) in

        if let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://library?AssetPath=\(videoURL.absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)&InstagramCaption=\(captionStr)") {
        print(instagramURL)

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(instagramURL as URL)
        }

        } else {
            print("NO")
        }
    }
}
```

I got instagramURL like this:

> instagram://library?AssetPath=file:%2F%2F%2Fhttp:%2Fmobmp4.org%2Ffiles%2Fdata%2F2480%2FTutak%252520Tutak%252520Tutiya%252520Title%252520Song%252520-%252520Remix%252520-%252520Drunx%252520-%252520Mp4.mp4&InstagramCaption=Some%20Preloaded%20Caption

And I successfully openURL but I can not found my video which I want to share on instagram.

Comment: decreased code indent but made indentation uniform and formatted response as quote

Comment: now i got success to share video on instagram.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know but It would be nice if you had add an answer explaining how you did it? Otherwise there is no benefit for us to know that you got success or not, right? :\

Comment: Can you tell us or share the code here so that we can also see how it is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func shareVideoToInstagram() {

   let videoFilePath = "http://mobmp4.org/files/data/2480/Tutak%20Tutak%20Tutiya%20Title%20Song%20-%20Remix%20-%20Drunx%20-%20Mp4.mp4"


   let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL)) {

      let url = URL(string: ("instagram://library?AssetPath="+videoFilePath))

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
        }

    } else {
        print(" Instagram isn't installed ")
    }

  }
```

Comment: you have to add in Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array -> Item 0 : instagram.

Comment: I added, but it doesn't help.

Comment: not working, do not try

Comment: not working, do not try

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a NSData from video:

```
guard
    let videoPath = "http://mobmp4.org/files/data/2480/Tutak%20Tutak%20Tutiya%20Title%20Song%20-%20Remix%20-%20Drunx%20-%20Mp4.mp4",
    let videoUrl = URL(string: videoPath),
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl)
else {
    
    return
}
    
postVideoToInstagramFeed(videoData: videoData)
```

and share with the function:

```
func postVideoToInstagramFeed(videoData: NSData) {
    
    getLibraryPermissionIfNecessary { granted in
        
        guard granted else { return }
    }
    
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(Date().description).mp4"
        
        videoData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    },
    completionHandler: { success, error in
        
        if success {
            
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            
            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
            
            if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
                
                let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
                let urlFeed = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
                
                guard
                    let url = URL(string: urlFeed)
                else {
                    
                    print("Could not open url")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                        
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Sucess")
                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            
                            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                            print("Sucess")
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        print("Instagram not found")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if let error = error {
            
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            
            print("Could not save the video")
        }
    })
}

func getLibraryPermissionIfNecessary(completionHandler: @escaping  (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    guard PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized else {
        completionHandler(true)
        return
    }
    
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        completionHandler(status == .authorized)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank for update.  We should modificationDate instead of creationDate.   fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: false)]

Comment: What if the Instagram app does not have permission to access shared assets? It's showing the "Something went wrong, please try again later." error message on the Instagram app.